# filtrar resultados por rango de fechas Angular Material

Tags: html5, css3, angularjs-2.0

Buenas, a ver si me podeis ayudar que estoy yo muy verde con **Angular Material**

tengo una tabla con N registros y estoy intentando hacer un filtro por un rango de fechas. tengo un *select* con las opciones (1 dia, 5 días, 1 semana, 15 días), los cuales se cargan con una veriable

JS

```
vm.rangos=[
     {id:"1",name:'1 día',value:'1'},
     {id:"2",name:'5 días',value:'5'},
     {id:"3",name:'1 Semana',value:'7'},
     {id:"4",name:'15 días',value:'15'}
  ];
```

HTML

```
<div layout="row" flex="90" layout-align="start center">
                        <label flex="25">Rango</label>
                        <select flex="60" ng-model="vm.rangoSelected" placeholder="" ng-options="ran.name for ran  in vm.rangos" class="selectPersonalizado ">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

y sinceramente no sé como hacer la función para realizar el filtro para mostrar los resultados de dentro del rango seleccionado

En esta función recojo el value de lo seleccionado

```
function sendFilter(){
      var filterSend = "";
      switch(vm.filterSelected){

          case 'rango':
            filterSend = vm.rangoSelected.value;
          break;
          default:
            alert('no hecho');
          break;

      }
      vm.showLastMovements(filterSend);
  }
```

En la cual con el alert, me saca bien el value del select.

si me podeis ayudar o por lo menos dar alguna pista para crear dicha función para luego hacer la llamada desde el *case* para que se muestren los resgistros de dicha seleccion os lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien el propósito de tu switch, pero imagino que es para saber si se ha seleccionarlo un filtro y aplicarlo o no. Para eso bastaría con un simple if. Te explico como tengo yo un filtro parecido montado.

En el select, tengo el primer option como 'No filtrar' con el value NO, y después pongo el resto de opciones. En el controlador inicializo vm.rangoSelected= 'NO':

```
<select ng-model="vm.rangoSelected">
  <option value="NO">No filtrar</option>
  <option ng-repeat="ran in vm.rangos" value="{{ran.value}}">{{ran.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Después, paso a la función de filtro el valor seleccionado. Tu función de filtro debería hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
function filtrar(lista, rango){
  var inicio = // la fecha - rango.
  var fin = // la fecha + rango.
  if(rango === 'NO') {
    return lista;
  } else {
    return lista.filter(function(elemento){ 
      return elemento.fecha >= inicio && elemento.fecha <= fin;
    });
  }
)
```

Para trabajar con fechas te recomiendo [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) con el que puedes sumar fechas fácilmente: `moment().add(7, 'days');` o comprobar si una fecha está dentro del rango: `fecha.isBetween(inicio, fin);`

Comment: Tengo 5 filtros, por numero de reultados, enter 2 fechas, este del rango de fechas (15 dias, 1 semana, 1 dias...) y por eso tengo el switch, que segun lo que se seleccione haga un filtro u otro. buscando por internet ya encontré la forma de hacerlo y una vez hecho a ultima hora de la tarde me dicen que lo tengo que hacer de otra manera utilizando querys y bueno, creo que ya lo tengo hecho, muchas gracias